# can't remove li element

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a to-do list app.

I'm able to add `li` elements (i.e. user tasks) when clicking on the '+' button.

However, I'd like to remove `li` elements when clicking on them. But when I click on a `li` element or task added by a user nothing happens.

```js
function dark() { // setting up dark-mode 
  var element = document.body;
  element.classList.toggle("dark-mode"); //dark-mode class
}

let addToDoButton = document.getElementById('addToDo');
let toDoContainer = document.getElementById('newTask');
let inputField = document.getElementById('tasks');
let removeButton = document.getElementById('remove');

addToDoButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var input = document.createElement('li')
  input.classList.add('tasks')
  input.innerText = inputField.value;
  toDoContainer.appendChild(input);
  inputField.value = '\n';
  //input.style.textDecoration = "line-through";

})

input.addEventListener('click', function() {
  // input.style.textDecoration = "line-through";

  toDoContainer.removeChild(input);
  inputField.value = " ";
  //const task = document.getElementById("remove");
  //task.innerHTML = " ";
})
```

```html
<body id="dark-mode">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="toggle">
      <label class="switch">
        <input type="checkbox"onclick="dark()" checked>
        <span class="slider round">&#9728;</span>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="title">
      <h1>Today I will ...</h1>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="tasks" id="newTask">
      <input class="new" id="tasks" type="text" placeholder="Task to be completed..."> <br>
      <button id="addToDo">+</button><br>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="added">
    <ul>
      <!--tasks show here-->
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: Please fix this error: `"ReferenceError: input is not defined"`

Comment: `input.addEventListener()` needs to be inside the add button's event listener.

Comment: As @Barmar said, the problem is that input variable is defined inside the function handler of the event assigned to `addToDoButton`, so it is not accesible from outside that function. Ill suggest to move the `input.addEventListener('click'...` inside the `addToDoButton.addEventListener('click'...` in order to assign the event every time an input element is created.

Answer (score 1):

the `input` variable is not known in the global scope. I would recommend doing [event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation) from a static parent using the event object.

```js
function dark() { // setting up dark-mode 
  var element = document.body;
  element.classList.toggle("dark-mode"); //dark-mode class
}

let addToDoButton = document.getElementById('addToDo');
let toDoContainer = document.getElementById('newTask');
let inputField = document.getElementById('tasks');
let removeButton = document.getElementById('remove');

addToDoButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var input = document.createElement('li')
  input.classList.add('tasks')
  input.innerText = inputField.value;
  toDoContainer.appendChild(input);
  inputField.value = '\n';
})

toDoContainer.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  if([...toDoContainer.querySelectorAll('li.tasks')].includes(event.target)) {
      toDoContainer.removeChild(event.target);
  }
})
```

```html
<body id="dark-mode">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="toggle">
      <label class="switch">
        <input type="checkbox"onclick="dark()" checked>
        <span class="slider round">&#9728;</span>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="title">
      <h1>Today I will ...</h1>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="tasks" id="newTask">
      <input class="new" id="tasks" type="text" placeholder="Task to be completed..."> <br>
      <button id="addToDo">+</button><br>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="added">
    <ul>
      <!--tasks show here-->
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following lines are a problem:

```js
let toDoContainer = document.getElementById('newTask');
//...
toDoContainer.appendChild(input);
```

`#newTask` is a `<div>` that wraps around all of the ToDo list interface. So all of the `<li>` ended up below the `<button>` -- not in it's intended place within the `<ul>`.

```html
<div class="container">
<!-- Other HTML -->
  <div class="tasks" id="newTask">
    <input class="new" id="tasks" type="text" placeholder="Task to be completed..."> <br>
    <button id="addToDo">+</button><br>

      <!-- All <li> was appended here -->

  </div><!-- End of #newTask -->
</div><!-- End of .container -->
<div class="added">
  <ul>
    <!--tasks show here-->
  </ul>
</div>
```

Another problem is:

```js
input.addEventListener('click', function() {//...
```

The only time `input` was defined was within the first event handler. Since it was never declared or defined outside of that event handler, it is out of scope. There are few reasons why just moving `input` outside of the event handler wouldn't work as well.

- `input` is dynamically created within the event handler so it can't be defined anywhere else although it can be declared, thus bringing it into scope, but...
- `input` is pointing to `document.createElement('li')` making that particular reference pointing to a unique object. So at best you can bind each `<li>` to the click event as they are being created. Not that good, but possible, but I never tested it cause it's just too messy.

The best solution is to bind the click event to the `<ul>` then you never have to worry about keeping track of `<li>`, see [event delegation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#event_delegation) for details.

The example is a strpped down version of the OP. As long as you're careful about renaming anything in this code (if you actually want to that is), there shouldn't be any problems with adding the rest of the HTML back in.

**Details on the removal part is commented in the example**

```js
const add = document.getElementById('add');
const text = document.getElementById('text');
const list = document.querySelector('ul');

add.addEventListener('click', function() {
  const task = document.createElement('li')
  task.classList.add('tasks')
  task.innerText = text.value;
  list.appendChild(task);
  text.value = '';
})
// Bind click event to <ul>
list.addEventListener('click', removeItem);

function removeItem(e) {
  // If the user clicked a <li>...
  if (e.target.matches('li')) {
    // ... remove that <li>
    e.target.remove();
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="text" type="text" placeholder="Task to be completed...">
<button id="add">+</button><br>
<ul>
  <!--tasks show here-->
</ul>
```

Answer (score -2):

please use visibility='none' or use javascript to hide this element